# How to store volley response into HashMap?

Tags: android, android-volley

> i have created HashMap and JsonArrayRequest object as follows. Response is successfully retrieved but HashMap object url_maps size is zero.I want to use for loop in url_maps.

```
    HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // Creating volley request obj for Banner
    JsonArrayRequest bannerReq = new JsonArrayRequest(bannerUrl,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(msg, response.toString());
                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            url_maps.put("static key", "static value );
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(msg, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(bannerReq);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void jsonToMap(String t) throws JSONException {

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(t);
    Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

    while( keys.hasNext() ){
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        String value = jObject.getString(key); 
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    System.out.println("json : "+jObject);
    System.out.println("map : "+map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can change:

```
url_maps.put("static key", "static value );
```

to:

```
url_maps.put(obj.getString("static key"),obj.getString("static value"));
```